# How to improve loading speed of a layout based page that includes a Visualforce section?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

So here is my problem. I've added a VisualForce page to an object as a section in the page layout. The VisualForce page contains the apex:details tag that points to another object. This means its essentially loading two pages. How can I make the performance of the main object's layout fasteer.

It seems like the the salesforce page waits for the VisualForce page to load before its done loading unlike other iframes behavior on the web. Is my assumption correct?

If it is, how can I add the apex:detail without waiting for it to load before the main page loads?

Answer (score 1):

You could try optimizing your page, reducing query sizes and amounts, as well as the data on the page and the controller, or having it be hidden via the rendered attribute, and then calling a method on pageload that would render the detail veiw. Just some ideas, without exact code its a little hard to try to pin down why a page would be loading slowly.

Comment: my vf has no apex code, only have a component that includes the apex:detail

Comment: So, it looks something like 

`<apex:page>
<c:my_comp />
<apex:detail ... />
</apex:page>`  ??

Comment: Or is it a page set as a layout, with component that contains the detail?

Comment: its the component that contains the detail

Comment: I'd try to figure out a way to have that flagged as rendered="false", when loading the page, and once loaded (via page load or something similar), set the render attribute to true, and then rerender that section of the page, but not the rest. If its low enough on the page, the users probably wont even notice that it was delayed when loading.